# Primefaces ajax listener not invoked after upgrade

Tags: jsf, primefaces, wildfly, javabeans, primefaces-extensions

After a Primefaces upgrade from 6.0 to 8.0 - and a WildFly upgrade to use JakartaEE - my ajax event listener isn't called anymore. However the `onsuccess` and `oncomplete` JS is executed.

My XHTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="container">
            <p:graphicImage id="myImage" library="projectLib" name="logo.png"/>
            <pe:imageAreaSelect id="areaSelect" for="myImage" handles="true">
                <p:ajax event="selectEnd" listener="#{testBean.selectEndListener}" oncomplete="console.log('complete')" onsuccess="console.log('success')"/>
            </pe:imageAreaSelect>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

My bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

    public void selectEndListener(final ImageAreaSelectEvent e) {
        // do something
    }

}
```

Nothing unusual to see in the server logs. In my browser console, I see the following warning:

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

- Primefaces: 8.0
- Primefaces extensions: 8.0.4
- JSF: jboss-jsf-api_2.3_spec
- WildFly: 21.0.2.Final

Comment: Let me investigate it might be a bug.

Comment: Update: it looks like the listener attribute is completely ignored. If I fill in a non existing method in the listener EL, no exception is thrown and the page renders as usual. Even when I fill in some random chars in EL no exception is thrown, as long as it is between #{}

Comment: What version of Wilfly because I tested locally with Jetty and its all working.  I know there are issues I have seen with latest Wildfly 21 so I would back up to WildFly 18

Comment: Until PrimeFaces and PFE release "jakarta" versions of their JARS in 10.0.0 you won't be able to use EE9 spec which changes everything from `javax` package to `jakarta` package.

Comment: I am using WildFly 21.0.2.Final

Comment: And I have wildfly-jakartaee8-with-tools as dependency, so I suppose I am still using EE8

Comment: Yeah other users have reported bad behavior with 21 so try 20 or 19.  I am using WF18 just fine.

Comment: I found a workaround by calling a remoteCommand in the oncomplete. This remoteCommand then calls the bean's listener method. However I cannot pass the ImageAreaSelectEvent this way, can I?

Comment: Btw I proposed the above workaround because after a downgrade to WildFly 16 I still experience the same issue. So I am thinking it's a bug in Primefaces

Comment: Hmmm its possible but most likely a Mojarra bug that Wildfly uses.  You can create a reproducer in PF Test I would be glad to debug:  See PF Test: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: Thanks for the reproducer just tested with `mvn clean jetty:run -Pmyfaces23` and `mvn clean jetty:run -Pmojarra23` and both are working fine. So it proves its not JSF or Primefaces.  Your issue lies somewhere in Wildfly. I would report to Wildfly.

Comment: Does your template.xhtml contain a h:form?

Comment: My reproducer was missing a form indeed. But in the context of my project, I still cannot get it working. The graphicImage and imageAreaSelect are within an outputPanel that's within a h:form

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but it was after I configure the Wildfly session-cookie to http-only=true and secure=true, undoing this, mi application works again.

PF 7.0.17
Wildfly 20